# Job Offer - Appropriate way of saying "I'm not seeking/searching for a job change"

Tags: expressions

The title says pretty much it.

I'm responding to a job offer and I want to express that currently I'm not really seeking for a change (a company/job/other change).

How I write it?

Comment: Is this really a job offer? I.e., "We would like to offer you a position in our company at a salary of $400,000 dollars per year tentatively starting on June 1, 2015?"  or is this simply a "We have current job postings at our company that may be a good fit for you based on your resume we found online"?

Comment: @Jim Exactly the latter, thanks for pointing it out. How is called that "position information" message?

Comment: If you think this message was addressed specifically to you *by a human* then it might be worthy of a response-  *might*.  But if you think it was part of a mass mailing based on a computer-filtered search of a bank of resumes then I just delete them and move on.  I say *might* above because even in the case where they have specifically sent you a message they are really just (ph)ishing and a response means they've found *a live one*.  So unless you wish to start a relationship with that head-hunter/recruiter you're better off just ignoring than responding.

Comment: @Jim Again the case is the latter :P. The HR person who contacts me works for a specific company that fits my career path better than the one I'm currently on, so even if I don't apply right know, I want to "get the contact". Sorry for insisting but, is there a way to call (like 'job offer') the "letting me know about the position" message?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Seeking for a job change" isn't idiomatic.

*I'm not seeking a new position at this time.

I'm not looking to change jobs at this time.*